# How to add third party js files to Webpack bundle?

Tags: typescript, webpack

I'm new to Webpack and read similar posts on stackoverflow, but they didn't help me. I've successfully added my js files that is modules to bundle.js file, but want to add other files as well:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/dx.all.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/go-1.7.11.js"></script>
```

How can I add them using import clause? Should I add them to entry .ts file or in webpack.config.js file?

I've tried the following, but it doesn't work:

The entry .ts files:

```
import './../Scripts/jquery-3.2.1.js';
import './../Scripts/dx.all.debug.js';
import './../Scripts/go-1.7.11.js';

import { Caller } from './Caller';

window.onload = () => {
    let caller: Caller = new Caller();
    caller.execute();
};
```

UPDATE:

1) webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './Main.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    }
};
```

2) All other .js files are placed in the same folder where Main.js file is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before we go with any specific fix, here is the general concept of webpack

1. Webpack needs an `entry` point and `output` location
2. From the `entry`, when webpack runs, it builds a dependency graph
3. Webpack then processes all those resources in the dependency graph
4. One can configure `loaders` to do any resource (js, css, ts, etc) specific processing
5. The processed resources will be placed in `output` location

Coming to your question, one typically uses `require("./resource");` or `import` in the source files wherever its needed functionally. Not in `webpack.config.js`. As mentioned earlier, all webpack needs is an `entry`. The entry resource in turn should have the dependencies declared.

To solve the issue:

1. Make sure the `entry` is configured properly in `webpack.config.js`
2. Make sure you add the other js files using `require("")` or `import` in appropriate **source files**. The `imports` in your entry looks fine provided the path is relatively correct.

Please edit the OP to include your

- webpack.config.js
- folder structure

if the problem still persists.

UPDATE: 
You are trying to use TypeScript code but then again the webpack doesnt know anything about it. iow no typescript transpilation config there. Webpack can transpile typescript into javascript and is well documented [here](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/babel-loader/).

As mentioned earlier, `loaders` do the heavy lifting based on resource type. Suggest to give it a try with `babel-loader`.

Also, do make sure the dependencies are well defined in your source js/ts files. The `entry` file (i.e Main.js) should have all the required modules as dependencies (using `import` or `require`). From your post its not clear how the `Main.js` has dependency with `entry.ts`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Please, take a look at UPDATE in the original post.

Comment: @tesicg Updated the answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: I've created single bundle.js file that contains all .js files that is 3 my files and 3 third party files, but the application still doesn't work.

Comment: What about the `.ts` files ? Are they also bundled and made into `bundle.js` ?

Comment: No. Why do I need .ts files when I transpilled them to .js files?

Comment: Since you mentioned "all .js files" and the fact that the webpack config does not include any transpiler, did you happen to make sure your `.ts` files are transpiled and the resulting javascript too is included in `bundle.js`. Anyway, if all is well and you are still getting error then please do post that. Without adequate information its hard to predict any solution.